# webpack-merge entry point

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, webpack-dev-middleware, webpack-hot-middleware

I have broken up my webpack config files in to 3 separate files as suggested in webpack 4.1 docs using webpack-merge to merge them together.

- webpack.common.js
- webpack.dev.js
- webpack.prod.js

The problem I'm running into is i'm using **webpack-dev-middleware** & **webpack-hot-middleware** and I only need to have this in webpack.dev.js which I do but the entry point requires the use of

```
  entry: [
    `${ROOT_DIR}/js/index`,
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client'
  ],
```

And thats in my webpack.common.js file. 
This means that prod and dev are going to have the 'webpack-hot-middleware/client' in their entry points. 
How can I get around only having **'webpack-hot-middleware/client'** in dev enry point and not in prod, using my setup with webpack-merge ?

I tried adding the entry in common with just this.

```
  entry: [
    `${ROOT_DIR}/js/index`
  ]
```

then in webpack.dev
      entry: [
        `${ROOT_DIR}/js/index`,
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client'
      ],

but that just caused duplication errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff in common is used in both dev & prod. So only include `'webpack-hot-middleware/client'` in the dev entry, it'll automatically get merged with the entry for `index` from common.

Comment: Thanks olore I had to remove entry from common and only have it in dev and prod which then worked. When I added it to common and the other two it gave me an error.